# Hide UILabel in UITableViewCell when scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using UITableView to display data. I put 1 UILabel inside each cell. I want to hide these UILabel when scroll. I have tried this but nothing happened.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    homeButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    HomeCell *cell = [[HomeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:nil];
    cell.timeLeft.hidden = YES;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting approach but making something disappear while scrolling seems to be a bad idea. It can be very annoying. If this is an experiment, then that's ok, but I would urge you to revise your design if you want to build this into an app.

Comment: @allprog Thank u for your advice. I will think about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. Have a `BOOL isScrolling` as a private variable and implement the following scrollview delegates. I hope this is what you wanted.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{        
    if(!decelerate)
    {
        isScrolling = NO;

        NSArray *visibleRows = [self.aTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
        [self.aTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:visibleRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
    else
    {
        isScrolling = YES;        
    }
}

-(void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    isScrolling = NO;
    NSArray *visibleRows = [self.aTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    [self.aTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:visibleRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}


-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    isScrolling = YES;
    NSArray *visibleRows = [self.aTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    [self.aTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:visibleRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

}
```

Note : I have used the textLabel which comes with UITableViewCell by default, and in cellForRowAtIndexPath: I am doing this :

```
if(isScrolling)
    [cell.textLabel setHidden:YES];
else
    [cell.textLabel setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Work like a charm ^^!.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a `NSNotification` for this.

In the `HomeCell` class in the `awakeFromNib` method do...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showLabel) name:@"ShowLabelsInCells" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideLabel) name:@"HideLabelsInCells" object:nil];
```

Then create the methods `showLabel` and `hideLabel`.

Then in the `UITableViewController` you can watch for the scrollview scrolling (and stopping scrolling) and call...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ShowLabelsInCells" object:nil];
```

and...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"HideLabelsInCells" object:nil];
```

When you need them.

No iterating through cells required.

Comment: What about when you need to create a new cell while already scrolling? (I like the idea though for modifying the existing cells)

Comment: Also, you must call `removeObserver:` before the Cell is deallocated. The app will likely crash without it.

Comment: Well, ay cells that are dequeued will have the label hidden/unhidden anyway. The variables persist when the cell is dequeued. Perhaps you could use a property in the controller so that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can set it just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing there is creating an entirely new cell, which is never and will never be on screen, and setting its label to hidden.

Instead, you should be setting a property on the controller to indicate that scrolling is in progress. Then you should iterate the visible cells on the table view and modify them. And when returning new cells you should check the flag to decide what to do.

You should reset the flag when you get the delegate callback telling you that the scrolling animation has completed.